# position = "dodge" doesn't dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm working on plotting two bar charts in R where I have confidence intervals for one of the bars and am running into the problem that position = "dodge" or position = position_dodge() doesn't shift the bars at all.  I viewed the similar questions on stackoverflow, but they seem to be coming up short.

My code is:

```
ggplot(data = Estimates.df, aes(x = Assets, y = Estimate, group = Estimate)) +
  geom_bar(data = Estimates.df, aes(x = Assets, y = Estimate, group = Estimate, fill = Estimate), stat = "identity", fill = "Blue", position = "dodge") +
  geom_bar(data = Estimates.df, aes(x = Assets, y = Target, group = Target, fill = Target), stat = "identity", fill = "Black", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = (Estimate - 1.645*Std..Error), ymax = (Estimate + 1.645*Std..Error), group = Estimate), position = "dodge")
```

I need the confidence intervals on the Estimate plot, but not on the Target plot.  I tried converting the dataframe to long via melt, but couldn't keep the confidence intervals that way.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

My data is:

```
Assets <- c("TW", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset4", "Asset5", "Asset6", "Asset7", "Asset8", "Asset9", "Asset10", "Asset11", "Asset12", "Asset13", "Asset14", "Asset15", "Asset16")
Std..Error <- c(.0002,.050,.0147,.028,.0289,.035,.0184,.0709,.0130,.0356,.0071,.0067,.0080,.0162,.0188,.0099,.0147)
Estimate <- c(.002,-0.032,.0317,.018,.0336,.0426,.09774,.3191,.0067,.0892,.0225,-0.0145,.0263,.01125,.07359,.09055,.1843)
Target <- c(0,.05,0,.04,0,0,.07,.23,0,.18,.05,0,.02,0,.09,.05,.22)

Estimates.df <- data.frame(cbind(Assets, Std..Error, Estimate, Target))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you supply a cut down data set that reproduces your problem? That way we can show you code that fixes it. Are you trying to have the estimates, blue be side by side the assets, black?

Comment: Absolutely! I added in the code to reproduce it. Yeah, ideally, the blue bar would be on top of the black bar for each Asset, with the error bars tied with the blue bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use long data. I use melt to do this and fiddle with the result a bit before plotting so you don't get error bars for Target as you said. Also I prefer creating the ymin and ymax before.
Below is what i believe you are asking for except for the colouring.

```
library(reshape2)
Estimates.df <- data.frame("Assets" = c("TW", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset4", "Asset5", "Asset6", "Asset7", "Asset8", "Asset9", "Asset10", "Asset11", "Asset12", "Asset13", "Asset14", "Asset15", "Asset16"),
                           "Std..Error" = c(.0002,.050,.0147,.028,.0289,.035,.0184,.0709,.0130,.0356,.0071,.0067,.0080,.0162,.0188,.0099,.0147),
                           "Estimate" = c(.002,-0.032,.0317,.018,.0336,.0426,.09774,.3191,.0067,.0892,.0225,-0.0145,.0263,.01125,.07359,.09055,.1843),
                           "Target" = c(0,.05,0,.04,0,0,.07,.23,0,.18,.05,0,.02,0,.09,.05,.22))

Estimates.df.p <- Estimates.df %>% 
  mutate(ymin = Estimate - 1.645*Std..Error, ymax = Estimate + 1.645*Std..Error) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c("Assets", "ymin", "ymax", "Std..Error"), value.name = "value", variable.name = "variable") %>% 
  mutate(ymin = ifelse(variable == "Target", NA, ymin),
         ymax = ifelse(variable == "Target", NA, ymax))


ggplot(data = Estimates.df.p, aes(x = Assets, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable, colour = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, group = variable), position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several errors, you need your data in the long format for `ggplot2` (not the wide format) so I use gather with `tidyr` and `dplyr` to convert to long format. Then you shouldn't repeat the aesthetics in each argument of ggplot. Finally you need to ensure that your values are of type `numeric` because they were of type `factor`.

```
Estimates.df <- data.frame(cbind(Assets, Std..Error, Estimate, Target))
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
Estimates.df<-Estimates.df %>%
  gather(type,value,Estimate:Target)


ggplot(data = Estimates.df, aes(x = Assets, y = value, fill=type, color=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge")+
  coord_flip() +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = (as.numeric(value) - 1.645*as.numeric(Std..Error)),
        ymax = (as.numeric(value) + 1.645*as.numeric(Std..Error))),
    position = "dodge")
```

[image]